# How to perform method exchange for RestTemplate in order to not change the uri

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

In order to get Json Content from a xwiki Rest API, I used RestTemplate's method RestTemplate.exchange(..) but I get a 404 not found error. The Uri contains %2520 instead of %20.

Here My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{   
    private static final String link = "http://swininducasa02.ptx.fr.sopra:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-8.4.5/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main/spaces/PIC/spaces/Serveur%20de%20virtualisation/spaces/Serveur%20de%20Marcoussis/spaces/choix/spaces/SGBFV/pages/WebHome";
    String plainCreds = "user:passwd";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    System.out.println("Begin /GET request!");
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(link+ "?media=json", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
    Map<String, String> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), Map.class);
    System.out.println( map.get("content"));
}
```

I searched & I found that the problem refers to the Content-Type . I tried all of the following lines but it is still not working.

headers.add("Content-type",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(link).build(true);
URI uri= uriComponents.toUri();
```

Here is the link that i want to access:

http://swininducasa02.ptx.fr.sopra:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-8.4.5/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main/spaces/PIC/spaces/Serveur%20de%20virtualisation/spaces/Serveur%20de%20Marcoussis/spaces/choix/spaces/SGBFV/pages/WebHome?media=json

But my request is going to:

http://swininducasa02.ptx.fr.sopra:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-8.4.5/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main/spaces/PIC/spaces/Serveur%2520de%2520virtualisation/spaces/Serveur%2520de%2520Marcoussis/spaces/choix/spaces/SGBFV/pages/WebHome?media=json

The character %20 becomes %2520. I used exchange because I have to set Auth headers

Please, can you help me?

Comment: what does uri.toString() return? I dont think this problem is related to your content-type, its double encoding your URI, possibly because you are passing it as an already-encoded String and not a URI

Comment: @WillM. sorry i just made a mistake when i copied the code

it refers to : link + "?media=json"  ( code above updated )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exchange(...)` is encoding your URI a second time. Try building the URI using `UriComponentsBuilder.build(true)` instead (the `true` says that your URI is already encoded). I see in your post you say you tried that, but it looks like you converted it back into a string when passing it to `exchange()` which probably resulted in it getting encoded a second time anyways.

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(link).queryParam("media","json").build(true);
URI uri= uriComponents.toUri();
```

or

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(path + "?media=json").build(true);
```

should be ok too. And then to use it, do

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

instead of

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString()+ "?media=json", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

Comment: big thanks  @Will  , I stayed all the day fixing this code

forHttpUrl is the function i needed .